# bootstrap 3 widen table

Tags: php, django-bootstrap3

I currently have this table:
[image]

as you can see in the action one is below the other. That sould be all 4 next to eachother.
when I increase the width of that action the other become smaller but I dont want that.

I want at least that the action show next to eachother and the model is on one line so Bluetooth station 9300 serie is now on 2 lines I want that preferably on one line.

For some reason I cant widen the whole table and it stays fixed in this width.

I am using bootstrap 3

This is my code for the table headers:

```
echo "<tr>";
             echo "<th>Merk</th>";
             echo "<th>Model</th>";
             echo "<th>voorraad</th>";
             echo "<th>threshold</th>";
             echo "<th>Action</th>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us the HTML of the table itself. We now only have a tiny bit of PHP which makes the header.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware full code is here:https://pastebin.com/5niYMcT3

Comment: That's the PHP code... not the HTML. It's helpful, but I can't run it.

Comment: This is the index page. this is all the code that shows that table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS property? Use:

```
 <td style="white-space: nowrap;"> .... icons .... </td>
```

Comment: @klaas123 You have applied it to the table cells containing the icons? And the icons are direct descendants of that cell?

Comment: Lastly: The icon's have to have the CSS property: `display: inline;`

Comment: @klaas123 Sorry, I don't know where I had my head, and made a stupid syntax error in my answer. I corrected it now, and it seems to work. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oa6fq0j9/). Make it narrower to see that the icons stay on one line.

Comment: when i paste this in my code it doesnt do anything. just keeps it the same way it was